# Run script after DHCP acknowledge or after succesful WiFi connection

Tags: networking, wireless, scripts, dhcp

I would like to register a callback script, which would fire after DHCP acknowledge.

Polling is an option...

Is it possible at all, without driver/kernel modification?

Comment: May be possible with dbus and network-manager . I'll see what can be done

Answer (score 1):

The script below basically polls for output of `ip addr`. Once there is something , the while loop terminates, and moves on to launch whatever else you specify. Replace `wlan0` with your wireless interface, and `zenity --info` part with whatever script you want to run. You may want to use `exec /path/to/script.sh arg1 arg2` to replace the process.

```
#!/bin/bash

wifi_info=$(ip -4 -o addr  show wlan0 )

while [ -z "$wifi_info" ];
do
   wifi_info=$(ip -4 -o addr  show wlan0 )
   sleep 0.25
done

zenity --info --text="WE'RE ONLINE!!!"
```