# Execute script on ethernet plug in/out

Tags: networking, scripts, events

I'm trying to automatically execute a custom script every time i plug in or out the ethernet cable.
I'm on Ubuntu 15.10 and nothing so far has worked. First i tried creating a script in /etc/network/if-up.d/, changing it's permissions so it can be run. The script was a simple bash script just to make sure it was executed at the exact moment i wanted:

```
#!/bin/bash          
sudo echo "script Executed"  > testPlugIn.log
```

It did not work when i plugged or unplugged the ethernet cable but it did work when I restarted the network sistem
    sudo service networking restart
But that's not what i wanted.
Next i tried creating an udev rule. I wrote the following rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/:

```
KERNEL=="enp3s0",RUN+="/usr/bin/my_script"
```

It also did not work.
Finally i found that i could use the command inotifywait. To test if it worked i did the following:

```
inotifywait -e modify /sys/class/net/enp4s0/carrier; echo 'change detected'
```

And did not work either. I plugged and unplugged the ethernet cable and nothing happened.
Any idea of what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The udev approach looks the most promising to me - does it make a difference if you add  `ACTION=="add"` or `ACTION=="remove"` to the rule? with no `ACTION` I *think* the script likely only runs once (on node creation)

Comment: I've written something like this before. Basic idea is to poll for the interface ip address. I'll link it once i find

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/793424/295286 See this, you just need to adapt it to your Ethernet interface name.

Comment: Question: do you want execute one specific script upon  plug in/plug out event or do you want to have two different events - one for plug in and one for plug out ? The same one means it's going to be far simpler and less lines of code

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers.  @steeldriver I tried to modify the udev rule as you said. I added ACTION=="add" but no luck. It just executes the rule when rebooting the system not when the ethernet cable is plugged in or out.

Comment: @Serg I want to execute the same script wether it's plug in or plug out.  I've read the link you posted, thanks. I will try to make a version of it that executes more than once. I need it to be monitoring the ethernet ports constantly. Could this solution be too cpu demanding if i do that? I'll try.

Comment: I will share the udev rule that i tried but did not work when plug in or plug out just in case anyone notices what i'm doing wrong:  `KERNEL=="enp3s0", ATTR{address}=="macaddress", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/path/to/script"`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I "wait for the network to go down, then do something":

```
#!/bin/bash
# Monitor for the net going down, Do The Next Thing (from a config file)
# to bring the net up. Implicit assumpition that The Next Thing fixes it
# may be a problem.
# Walt Sullivan

# Note: places where you may need to adjust things to match 
# your environment/taste are marked "#Adjust"

# determine my name
me=$0
me=${me##*/}

# my variables
debug=0             # set via --debug
verbose=0           # set via --verbose
original=""         # set the <config.file>
original_update=0       # time <config.file> was last modified
config="/var/tmp/${me}.$$.config" # my writable copy of config
result=""             # temporary use

# $ dpkg -S $(type -p nm-online)
# network-manager: /usr/bin/nm-online
# $ dpkg -S $(type -p ip)
# iproute2: /sbin/ip
# man ip-link;man ip-monitor;man ip-address;man 7 regex

# -h or --help or something's wrong in here
help () {
    echo "${me} [-h|--help] [-v|--verbose] <config.file> " >&2
    echo "" >&2
    echo "Monitor the wireless network, and when it goes down, Do The" >&2
    echo "Next Thing (as specified by the <config.file>), to bring" >&2
    echo "the wireless net up." >&2
    echo "" >&2
    echo "The <config.file> contains #comments, blank lines, AND" >&2
    echo "single line commands, of your choice, to correct the" >&2
    echo "wireless network down condition. The first command in the" >&2
    echo "<config.file> will be executed the first time the net goes" >&2
    echo "down (or if the net is down when ${me} begins), the second" >&2
    echo "command will be executed the next time the net goes down," >&2
    echo "and so forth, wrapping around at the end. The number of" >&2
    echo "single line commands in the <config.file> is unlimited." >&2
    exit 2
}

function flip () {
    # Return the first non-blank, non #comment line,
    # and move that line (and all preceeding blank and #comment
    # lines) to the end of (our copy of) the config file.
    #
    # ed pattern includes "/", but not "~" or "."
    #Adjust the ed pattern in both places and in countconfiglines
    ed --quiet "$config" <<EndOfEd
/^[A-Za-z0-9\/]/
1,.t$
1,/^[A-Za-z0-9\/]/d
wq
EndOfEd
}

function countconfiglines () {
    # return number of config file lines
    #Adjust must match the ed pattern in flip()
    configfile="$1"
    egrep --count '^[[:alnum:]/]' "$configfile"
    }

function up-to-date () {
    # updates configuration file if necessary
    new_update="$(/usr/bin/stat --format='%Y' $original )"
    if [[  "$new_update" -ne "$original_update" ]] ; then
    if [[ $(countconfiglines "$original") -eq 0  ]] ; then
        echo "Invalid configuration in $original" >&2
        exit 4
    else
        /bin/cp --force "$original" "$config"
        original_update="$new_update"
    fi
    fi
    }

function netstate () {
    # Return network state as "UP" or "DOWN"
    #Adjust how you decide net is UP/DOWN
    ip link show | egrep -q 'UP,LOWER_UP.* state UP'
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo "UP"
    else
    echo "DOWN"
    fi
}

# Execution begins here

# parse the args with getopt, adapted from
# /usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/getopt-parse.bash

TEMP=`getopt -o dhv --long debug,help,verbose \
     -n "${me}" -- "$@"`

if [[ $? != 0 ]] ; then echo "${me} --help for help." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi

# Note the quotes around `$TEMP': they are essential!
eval set -- "$TEMP"

while true ; do
    case "$1" in
    -d|--debug) debug=1; shift;;
    -h|--help) help; shift;;
    -v|--verbose) verbose=1; shift;;
    --) shift; break;;
    *) echo "Internal error! ${me} --help for help";exit 1;;
    esac
done

# Did we get the <config.file>?
original="$1"
shift
[[ -z "$original" ]] && \
    (echo "Missing config file ${me} -h for help" >&2 ; exit 1)

# If there are more parameters, confusion exists in the mind of the caller
[[ "$#" -ne 0 ]] && help

[[ -r "$original" ]] || (echo "${me}:Cannot read $original" >&2
                exit 2)

if [[ $(countconfiglines "$original" ) -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo "${me}:Invalid configuration in $original" >&2
    exit 4
else
    # watch for changes, record "%Y time of last modification,
    # seconds since Epoch"
    original_update="$(/usr/bin/stat --format='%Y' $original )"

    # make a writeable copy for our use, and clean it up at the end
    # unless $debug
    [[ $debug -ne 0 ]] || trap "/bin/rm -f $config" EXIT
    /bin/cp --force "$original" "$config"
fi

# if the net is down, Do The Next Thing right away
#Adjust: how you decide the net is up or down?
[[ "$(netstate)" = "DOWN" ]] && \
    ( result="$(flip)";
    [[ $verbose ]] && echo "$(date):$result" >&2; \
        eval "$result" )

# Wait for the net to go down, then Do The Next Thing
#Adjust find a better way to watch for net down 
ip monitor address | \
    egrep --line-buffered \
    '^Deleted [[:digit:]]+: [[:alnum:]]+[[:space:]]+inet[[:space:]].* scope global ' | \
    while read line ; do
    up-to-date
    result="$(flip)"
    [[ $verbose -eq 1 ]] && echo "$(date):$result" >&2
# Here is where "The Next Thing" is Done
    eval "$result"
done
# we never exit the while loop, until the world ends.
exit 0
```

Comment: Don't use `echo` to print each and every line of help text. Use `cat` with `here-document`.  See [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/755229/295286) , specifically the `print_usage` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using NetworkManager the best way to react to changes in the network state is to put an executable inside `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`.

See the [“Dispatcher Scripts” section in the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/NetworkManager.8.html#contenttoc3):

> ### DISPATCHER SCRIPTS
>
> NetworkManager will execute scripts in the `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` directory or subdirectories in alphabetical order in response to network events. […]